# manage artwork game data for iphone/ipad/osx

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management

I looked for some hours, can't seem to find it anymore. There is a term for using some kind of a "artmap" for loading graphic parts inside your app?

For example, i make one file (jpg/tif/png?) with different buttons and other  visual items. Then i 'copy' just a specific rect from the 'map' and use it as a button, title whatever.

I'm looking for some info, and pointers how to implement with cocoa (iphone, ipad, osx).

Thanks!

Comment: Why? Separate images are easier to make, easier to use, and easier to dispose of selectively. You only need the images in memory that you're using, not the ones you're not. This is especially important on iOS, where you will occasionally be told by the system that memory is running low and you need to get rid of as much stuff as you can.

Comment: @Peter: On modern graphics hardware, performance for some applications is often dominated by the speed of state changes.  Using a texture atlas can cause drastic performance gains in some applications due to the reduced need for state changes.

Comment: @Dietrich, yeah, texture atlas thats the term i was looking for. Would you also use this technique with just core animation? Or for simple 2d drawing?

Comment: I would write the application normally, and use a texture atlas if profiling indicated it would be benificial.  It does make the code more complicated so you shouldn't do it unless the benefits are known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dietrich was saying its called a "Texture Atlas". Apple has some documentation for this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/AboutTextureAtlases/AboutTextureAtlases.html